# "metadata-generation-failed" error appears trying to install pygame

Tags: python, pip, path

When using the command "pip install pygame", the error message "metadata-generation-failed" appears, I have tried different commands like "python -m pip install pygame" and "py -m pip install pygame", but the same error message appears.

Comment: "pip.exe" is in a subdirectory of the installation directory ("Scripts", I think). You can either use the full path to run it or add the directory in environment variable "PATH".

Comment: @real_fan I've tried the answers to that question but I still get the "metadata-generation-failed" error message

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have also tried it with the Path containing Scripts but I still get the "metadata-generation-failed" message

Answer (score 0):

I have found a command which fixes the issue!
pip install pygame --pre

In the pip documentation, at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-pre ,
it says

> Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.

I'm not sure why downloading a pre-release or development version of pygame fixes the issue, but it does.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).